# Can I ask questions regarding towing here?

Tags: discussion

I have some questions regarding US parking laws and the legality of towing.

These questions aren't technically about travelling in any real sense, but Travel.SE sees and accepts plenty of questions regarding road law, is road law accepted here regardless?

If not, are they welcome anywhere on SE or should I ask elsewhere?

Comment: I presume you mean your car being towed for illegal parking, vs you towing a trailer?

Comment: Not regarding illegal parking, but yes. I will look elsewhere before I consider asking the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could make an argument that they're on topic.  However, parking laws in North America (U.S. and Canada, at least) are municipal, so they are going to vary widely by area.  They will likely even be different in different cities in a metropolitan area, e.g. Minneapolis versus St. Paul, or Dallas vs. Fort Worth vs. Arlington vs. Plano vs. Grapevine.